# Reading MNIST Image Database binary file in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, mnist

I have a binary file from the MNIST image database, renamed as "myfile.dat".  This consists of a set of 4 unsigned 32-bit integers, followed by a chain of unsigned 8-bit integers.  I want to read this file and store its contents as an array.  Here is my code:

```
file_id = fopen('myfile.dat', 'rb');
data = fread(file_id, 'int');
size(data)
class(data)
```

And the output is:

```
ans =

    2502           1


ans =

double
```

The size of (2502, 1) is as expected. But why is it telling me that the data is `double`, when I have specified it to be `int`?

I know what the first few numbers should be and the output data is not as expected. I have also tried `int32`, `uint` and `uint32` which give the same problem.

Comment: If you look at the documentation the `int` qualifier is not guaranteed to give you the right result.  Try specifying it as `int32`.  Also, when you display your data, is all of the data what you expect?  Are all of the numbers correct?  If it is, you can simply cast it to `int32` before you proceed.

Comment: Yes, I have tried int32 as well - together with uint and uint32. All I know is that the binary file is 32-bit integers, but I did not create it myself. The output data is not as I would expect - and I know what the first few numbers should be.

Comment: Can you post that file somewhere as well as what the first few numbers are expected to be?  We can diagnose further

Comment: Sure - the file can be downloaded at http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/. It is the t-10k-images file. The details on the file structure are at the bottom of the web page.

Comment: Heh, the MNIST database.  Hand digit recognition I assume?  I'll have a look and I'll let you know.  Which `t-10k` file?

Comment: It's the images file :)

Comment: The file is not uniform.  The first few digits are 32-bit, while the rest are unsigned 8-bit integer.  As such you'll have to write logic to accommodate for the uneven number sizes

Comment: Yes well I actually tried just reading in the first 4 digits by specifying the parameter in fread(), but it still gave me incorrect data.

Comment: I am to, but if you read in each number as an `uint8` type one at a time, the first four bytes reads `0,0,8,3`, which is what you expect.  I may have to hack my way through this.

Comment: I think it may be something to do with the `machinefmt` parameter of fread(). If I try `b` or `s`, then the output seems more reasonable (in fact, the second digit is correct), but it is still not fully as expected.

Comment: Figured out why.  The first four bytes when you set the type to `int32` are actually read in reverse order.  You're actually getting `3,8,0,0` when you read in one integer as 32-bit.  When you take this and convert it to decimal, you get a huge number (> 5000000).  What I had to do was read in the first 4 bytes, make sure they're stored as `0,0,8,3`, then use each number as 8 bits into the 32 bit number.

Comment: I'm done.  I'll post my answer now.

Comment: Thanks! Ok I'm just looking into this using the swapbytes() function. However, this still doesn't explain why it tells me the `class` of `data` is a `double` rather than an `int`?

Comment: My suspicion is that your data was coalesced so that `double` was the best data type to fit all of the numbers.  Anyway, my solution has been posted.  Take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With our comments, the way MATLAB reads in 4 integers at a time is in `little-endian` format while the file format of the MNIST database file is in `big-endian`.  As such, when we read in the first four bytes of the file, the bytes are `0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x03` as we expect.  However, MATLAB will read this in as `0x03, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00`.  When converting this to an integer, we actually will get `50855936` which is not what we want.

A hack to solve this would be when we need to read in several bytes at a time, we need to ensure that we specify the `uint8` data type.  This will store each byte into separate elements in an array.  We can then compute the necessary number we need by bit-shifting each byte over by a specified amount, then summing the results.  We will need to do this for the first few bytes in the data file.

Alternatively, we can use the `swapbytes` method as you have stated in your comments and that'll give us exactly the same thing.  You can just read 1 byte that is of a `uint32` type, then swap the order of the bytes so that the bytes are in `big-endian` format.  You'll need to bear in mind that even when you read in the data as `uint32`, the number will be stored in MATLAB as `double` so you will need to cast the number before going into `swapbytes`.

Once we get to the actual image data, we can read in `numRows x numCols` bytes at a time, then reshape the array so that it becomes an image.  We can store each image into a cell array.  Without further ado, here's the code.

```
clear all;
close all;

%//Open file
fid = fopen('t10k-images-idx3-ubyte', 'r');

%//Read in magic number
%//A = fread(fid, 4, 'uint8');
%//magicNumber = sum(bitshift(A', [24 16 8 0]));

%//OR
A = fread(fid, 1, 'uint32');
magicNumber = swapbytes(uint32(A));

%//Read in total number of images
%//A = fread(fid, 4, 'uint8');
%//totalImages = sum(bitshift(A', [24 16 8 0]));

%//OR
A = fread(fid, 1, 'uint32');
totalImages = swapbytes(uint32(A));

%//Read in number of rows
%//A = fread(fid, 4, 'uint8');
%//numRows = sum(bitshift(A', [24 16 8 0]));

%//OR
A = fread(fid, 1, 'uint32');
numRows = swapbytes(uint32(A));

%//Read in number of columns
%//A = fread(fid, 4, 'uint8');
%//numCols = sum(bitshift(A', [24 16 8 0]));

%// OR
A = fread(fid, 1, 'uint32');
numCols = swapbytes(uint32(A));

%//For each image, store into an individual cell
imageCellArray = cell(1, totalImages);
for k = 1 : totalImages
    %//Read in numRows*numCols pixels at a time
    A = fread(fid, numRows*numCols, 'uint8');
    %//Reshape so that it becomes a matrix
    %//We are actually reading this in column major format
    %//so we need to transpose this at the end
    imageCellArray{k} = reshape(uint8(A), numCols, numRows)';
end

%//Close the file
fclose(fid);
```

If you check the number of rows and columns (stored as `numRows`, `numCols`), the magic number (stored as `magicNumber`) and the total number of images (stored as `totalImages`), this should be equal to `2051, 28, 28` and `10000` respectively.  After this code, the `kth` element of `imageCellArray` will store the `kth` digit in the MNIST database.  If you do `imshow(imageCellArray{k});`, where `k` is any integer between `1` to `10000`, you should be able to see a digit.

Also, one final note: As reading in the matrix data will be in `double`, we need to cast this so that it's `uint8` as the images are of that type from the database.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! That works well now :). An alternative solution based on your method is to use the swapbytes function: `magic_num = swapbytes(uint32(data(1))) etc....`

Comment: @EddyJ: Cool!  Glad to know this!  I'll edit my post.

Comment: @EddyJ: Done.  Nice find with `swapbytes` and thanks for accepting my post.  Good luck!