# Unable to import data in matlab from a unlabelled file format

Tags: matlab, import, mnist

I have downloaded noisy MNIST dataset from

[data link](http://csc.lsu.edu/~saikat/n-mnist/)

but the file downloaded is of unknown file format its written in the description that the available file is in mat format so I renamed the uncompressed file to .mat format. but when I try to upload it to matlab it shows the folowing error

> Unable to read MAT-file F:\
>   data\mnist-with-motion-blur\mnist-with-motion-blur.mat. Not a binary
>   MAT-file. Try load -ASCII to read as text.

I have also used mnist helper function but it didn;t help.
[helper mnist](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Using_the_MNIST_Dataset)

Comment: have you tried to unzip it?

Comment: Yes I unzipped it @Adiel

Comment: Ok.. maybe try one of these (duplicates...?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580926/how-do-i-load-in-the-mnist-digits-and-label-data-in-matlab   ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127896/reading-mnist-image-database-binary-file-in-matlab

Comment: What Matlab function are you using to load the data? I just download the file n-mnist-with-awgn.gz from the link you provided. I extracted it using 7zip and had no problem loading it under Octave by simply calling: `A=load('C:\Users\Sheldon\Downloads\mnist-with-awgn.mat')`

Comment: I tried with WinZip and Matlab, and couldn't load it, also in the `-ascii` mode. But maybe `fread` will work, as in the links that I attached.

Comment: I found the answer I unzipped it in ubuntu and it has unzipped perfectly directly to mat

Comment: mm.. make some sense. I see that you came also with a solution for Windows... great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file in the link mentioned above is compressed as tar.gz when we decompress it it comes up in the file format of `tar` which can be further uncomperssed using `tar xvf mnist-with-awgn` then we get file in `mat` file format